# Getting cb() never called! Error from npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run the command 'set NODE_ENV= && npm ci', but I am getting an error from npm saying "cb() never called!"

I have done a lot of Googling to see others have had this issue, but none of the solutions I have found have worked. Also most of the posts I have seen are several years old so they could easily be outdated now.

Does anyone know how to go about resolving this issue?

Comment: full error preferably the entire output from console please.. be quick im sure will be closed as dupe: https://www.google.com/search?q=cb()+never+called+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: What does `npm ci` do?

Comment: @Phix clean install

Comment: Full output after entering the command.

npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation

npm ERR! cb() never called!


npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:

npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

I have omitted the log location for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

`Try switching your network`,
somehow switching network worked for me.

I have tried many things, like:

1. npm cache clean --force
2. Delete existing node_modules, delete package-lock.json, and reinstall using - npm i
3. npm cache verify
4. npm clean-install

`None of the above worked for me`, might work for you.
Try your luck.